# Remap Ctrl+Space?

Tags: keyboard, customization

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut is really important in *Mathematica* for using `Placeholder[]` boxes in input templates.  Unfortunately, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> occupies the significantly more important role of the system-wide [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/) shortcut that I'm not really willing to part with, not even while *Mathematica* is running.  Can I change this shortcut in *Mathematica* to some other key sequence?

Comment: Seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "important for using Placeholder[] boxes".  Control-Space is the shortcut for "End Subexpression", e.g. exiting the superscript after pressing Control-6.  You can do fine without it.  Just use the arrows to exit the superscript.  Can you explain what you're doing with Control-Space exactly?  I don't understand how it's related to Placeholder[].

Comment: @Szabolcs: I should clarify:  Yes, you can use the arrow keys, but moving out of subexpressions (containing placeholders, hence the reference) using the arrow keys while typing long expressions begins to hurt your wrists after 8+ hours straight or so.

Comment: Well, you can always edit KeyEventTranslations.tr and add a different alternate than right-arrow.   For my wrists I prefer a single key rather than a combination though.

Comment: I use Windows and use Ctrl+tab to exit subexpressions

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to everyone for the helpful comments.  Here's the exact procedure I used to fix this (specific to Mac OS X, version 10.8 if that matters, and Mathematica 8, but it should be analogously applicable to other versions and operating systems):

1. Close Mathematica
2. Delete the keymap cache.  For me this was in `~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/8.0 Caches/MacOSX-x86/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh`
3. Edit the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file.  For me this was in `/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh`.  For me, the relevant line was 120, reading `Item[KeyEvent[" ", Modifiers -> {Control}], "MoveExpressionEnd"],`
4. Reopen Mathematica.  The new keyboard shortcut is in place.

Comment: +1 for coming back and describing the solution in detail for everyone's benefit