# Simpler way to type Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x]

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, keyboard, templates

Though not unbearable, I always feel a little nervous when typing partial derivatives at a specified place e.g. $u^{(1,0)}(0,x)$, which happens a lot when setting initial/boundary conditions for PDEs. As far as I know, people usually turn to the following 2 ways to obtain the partial derivative:

```
(* 1 *)
Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x]
(* 2 *)
D[u[t, x], t] /. t -> 0
```

Both are tedious in my view. Is there a better way to input it? Create an auxiliary function? Shortcut? Template?

Answer (score 5):

I've thought out 2 auxiliary functions.

> A possible improvement for the `Derivative` approach:

```
d /: u_^d[a__][b__] := Derivative[a][u][b]
```

Then $u^{(1,0)}(0,x)$ can be obtained by

```
u^d[1, 0][0, x]
```

But I'm not sure if typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> is simpler than typing <kbd>[</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>…

> A possible improvement for the `D` approach:

```
d2[u_, y__] := 
 Module[{pos = Position[{y}, _Equal]}, 
  D[u, Sequence @@ MapAt[First, {y}, pos]] /. Rule @@@ Extract[{y}, pos]]
```

Then $u^{(1,0)}(0,x)$ can be obtained by

```
d2[u[t, x], t == 0]
```

Notice the syntax of `d2` is quite similar to `D` so you can do something like the following:

```
d2[u[t, y, x], t == 0, x, {t, 2}, x == 1, x]
```

> ```
> Derivative[3, 0, 3][u][0, y, 1]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

If you do this often why not create a shortcut or template as you mentioned in the question?  This has the advantage of formatting directly without having to use **Evaluate in Place** etc, or introducing a custom notation.  Example:

```
Derivative[Placeholder[], Placeholder[]][Placeholder[]] // 
  PasteButton // CreatePalette
```

Makes:

[image]

If preferred a keyboard shortcut can be added to `KeyEventsTranslation.tr` or a menu item to `MenuSetup.tr`.

- Note: you can enter additional arguments within the parentheses, e.g.:

  [image]

  ```
  (* Derivative[1,4,3,2][foo][bar,baz] *)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for showing the usage of `CreatePalette` etc. (I'm really unfamiliar with these stuff!) One disadvantage of template in my view, is that I can't move out of it in a easy way. (If I use `Tab`, the cursor just… loops! )

Comment: @xzczd Would `Derivative[Placeholder[], Placeholder[]][Placeholder[]][Placeholder[], 
   Placeholder[]] // PasteButton // CreatePalette` suit you better?  Or use right cursor key or End?

Comment: Personally I feel right cursor key and End aren't quite convenient since they're a little... far away from my finger. Anyway, your new added example is better, now I just need to type right cursor key only once :)

Comment: @xzczd Please try Ctrl + Space

Comment: Ctrl+Space is even more troublesome… see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24741/1871). But just noticed Rojo has mentioned the Ctrl+Tab shortcut in a comment under that post, and it seems to be a good choice.