# Solving a BC Differential equation, (Buckling) any way possible

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am trying to verify my manual solution for this problem by any way, so I tried NDSolve, and DSolve, with no success. 
Can some one help, or even give me the final numbers :D
I need the first 3 alphas for a buckling[image]

Here is my interpretation (yields the NDSolve::ivone error)

```
xDim = 1;
yDim = 1/2;

alpha = 4 Pi^2;

eqn2D = D[w[x, y], {x, 4}] + 2 D[w[x, y], {x, 2}, {y, 2}] + 
   D[w[x, y], {y, 4}] + alpha D[w[x, y], {x, 2}];

buck2D = NDSolve[{eqn2D == 0,
   w[-xDim, y] == 0,
   w[xDim, y] == 0,
   w[x, -yDim] == 0,
   w[x, yDim] == 0,
   Derivative[2, 0][w][-xDim, y] == 0,
   Derivative[2, 0][w][xDim, y] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 2][w][x, -yDim] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 2][w][x, yDim] == 0},
   w, {x, -xDim, xDim}, {y, -yDim, yDim}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines"}]
```

Even the 1D solution seems incorrect:

```
youngs = 2*^5;(*N/mm^2, steel*)

sideLength = 1.78;(*mm*)
areaMomInertia = sideLength^4/12;(*mm^2, square section*)

load = 42;(*N*)

alpha = load/(youngs areaMomInertia);

eqn1D = D[w[x], {x, 4}] + alpha D[w[x], {x, 2}];

buck1D = NDSolveValue[{eqn1D == 0,
   w[0] == 0,
   w[200] == 0,
   (D[w[x], {x, 1}] /. x -> 0) == 0,
   (D[w[x], {x, 1}] /. x -> 200) == 0},
  w, {x, 0, 200}]

Plot[buck1D[x], {x, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All]
```

References:

https://uta-ir.tdl.org/uta-ir/bitstream/handle/10106/300/umi-uta-1041.pdf
http://www.arpnjournals.com/jeas/research_papers/rp_2007/jeas_0207_35.pdf

Comment: Can you include your `NDSolve` code attempt?

Comment: NDSolve[{eqn==0,w[-1,y]==0,w[1,y]==0,w[x,-(1/2)]==0,w[x,1/2]==0,(w^(0,2))[x,-(1/2)]==0,(w^(0,2))[x,1/2]==0,(w^(2,0))[1,y]==0,(w^(2,0))[-1,y]==0},w,{x,-1,1},{y,-(1/2),1/2}]

Comment: Gives me the error Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. \
Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other \
independent variable.

Comment: `(w^(0,2))[x,-(1/‌​2)]==0` should be more like this `Derivative[0, 2][w][x, -1/2] == 0` ... and I was unclear ... please share enough code so we can run your `NDSolve` attempt

Comment: Also, please show us more background information, for example, what's "the first 3 alphas for a buckling"?

Comment: This is potentially an interesting question but you should clean the question up a bit, fix the errors and provide the complete code you have.

Comment: @xzczd  I added my own code and a reference to a paper solving this exact problem

Comment: @Young Then this problem is quite similar to this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135893/1871 . And I think the solution for this specific problem is `w[x,y]==0`?

Comment: @Young, while I see the crash in version 11.0 it seems fixed in current sources. So the crash should go away in the next release. But note that the FEM currently (V11.0) can not handle higher then second order spacial derivatives.

Comment: @user21 thanks for the feedback ... I was trying different stuff to avoid the `NDSolve::ivone` error and was surprised by the immediate crash ... Should `ExpandFunctionSymbolically` be `ExpandEquationsSymbolically` in the documentation here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#789821263

Comment: @xzczd The buckling equation is very similar to the biharmonic equation ... I found your answer there previously and tried the pure `NDSolve` version to no avail

Comment: @Young, yes, that looks right. I'll file a bug. Thanks.

Comment: OK
@Young: (w^(0,2)) and using  Derivative[0, 2][w] are basically the same thing. The alpha is the nondimensional load that will cause buckling. You can think of it an eigenvalue problem and alpha is the eigen values.

Comment: @xzczd So why did you set alpha = 4 Pi^2 ?

Comment: I set apha because I was going to compare results to a problem detailed in one of the references I found

Comment: No, `(w^(0,2))` is meaningless, it just _looks_ correct, the `StandardForm` of `Derivative` can't be typed in this way, check [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114672/1871) for more details. Then, if this is an eigenvalue problem, I think your problem is similar to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128239/1871).

Comment: @young I guess you've mixed [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135893/1871) up with [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94639/1871)?

Comment: @xzczd I'm not sure what you mean. I haven't seen the first link ("this question")

Comment: @young I mean there exists several posts whose name involves "biharmonic" and I've answered 2 of them, but the [previous mentioned post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137154/solving-a-bc-differential-equation-buckling-any-way-possible?noredirect=1#comment370507_137154) doesn't contain a pure `NDSolve` approach. Actually this type of equation i.e. stationary biharmonic equation can't be solved with `NDSolve` directly, because 1. `"MethodOfLine"` only handles well-posed initial value problem. 2. Currently `"FiniteElement"` can only deal with equation no more than 2nd order.

Comment: @xzczd now I understand ... the day "FiniteElement" inside NDSolve can handle 3rd order or higher will be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Since you just want to verify your manual solution *by any way*, let me show you a solution based on [`finiteFourierSinTransform`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155818/1871).

```
dim@x = 1;
dim@y = 1/2;

Clear[alpha]

With[{w = w[x, y]}, 

 eqn = D[w, {x, 4}] + 2 D[w, {x, 2}, {y, 2}] + D[w, {y, 4}] + alpha D[w, {x, 2}] == 0;

 help = ({w == 0, D[w, {#, 2}] == 0} /. List /@ {# -> -dim@#, # -> dim@#} // Flatten) &;

 {bc@x, bc@y} = help /@ {x, y}]
```

Then make finite Fourier sine transform with respect to $x$, and substitute `bc@x` in:

```
Format@finiteFourierSinTransform[f_, __] := Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalF], s][f]

ffst = finiteFourierSinTransform;
{teq, tbc@y} = ffst[{eqn, bc@y}, {x, -dim@x, dim@x}, n] /. (Rule @@@ bc@x /. y -> y_)
```

Once again, make finite Fourier sine transform. This time we eliminate derivatives with respect to $y$:

```
tteq = ffst[teq, {y, -dim@y, dim@y}, m] /. 
     ffst[ffst[a_, b__], c__] :> ffst[ffst[a, c], b] /. (Rule @@@ tbc@y /. 
      x -> x_) /. (Rule @@@ bc@x /. y -> y_) // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At this point, it's clear that $w$ only has a trivial solution, unless the coefficient `(-4 alpha n^2 + (4 m^2 + n^2)^2 Pi^2)` equals zero, which is relevant to buckling. It's clear that `m` and `n` won't be that large for first 3 `alpha`s, so let's find them by brute force:

```
alphavalue = Solve[tteq[[1, 1]] == 0, alpha][[1, 1, -1]]
Sort@Union@Flatten[Table[{alphavalue, {n, m}}, {m, 5}, {n, 5}], 1][[1 ;; 3]]
(* {{4 π^2, {2, 1}}, {(169 π^2)/36, {3, 1}}, {(25 π^2)/4, {1, 1}}} *)
```

The first one is `4 π^2`, which is exactly the value tested in your question.